# Is there any way to extract only few fields from mongo document without fetching all the fields first

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have written follwing code to exract only "value" field including "_id" from a mongodb collection:

```
db.collection("some collecion name").find({},{"value":1})
```

But I suppose it will first fetch all the fields, then apply the filter.
Is there any way to stop it from fetching all other fields, since I dont need them here ?

Comment: downvote as it is the defined way in the doc

Answer (score 1):

that's the correct way of doing it. read more about [Project Fields to Return from Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Comment: Yeah now I got it. It's equivalent to the SQL query: SELECT value,_id from Collection_Name